# Laravel Dusk Proxy как подключиться

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, webdriver

Как можно выполнять тесты laravel dusk с использованием proxy, авторизирующегося через диалоговое окно браузера (логин+пароль)?

Также, насколько понимаю, заголовки авторизации нельзя передавать и логи `login:pass@server.com:3323` выдает ошибку подключения.

Возможно, кто знает, как использовать стандартный браузер со всеми его настройками или хотя бы как запускать браузер со специальным расширением, которое может автологинить? Или знает, как можно прописать данные авторизации, чтобы сразу логинило? Есть HTTP і SOCKS5.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно для этого делают бекдор на уникальном рандомном урле без авторизации, который раз в сутки обновляется, типа dfksfksdpf2349280.вашсайт.ру или вашсайт.ру/dfksfksdpf2349280 и не парятся с авторизацией.
Автоматическая авторизация это зло и боль, не надо этим увлекаться